# Handling POSIX socket read() errors

Tags: c++, sockets, error-handling, client

Currently I am implementing a simple client-server program with just the basic functionalities of read/write.

However I noticed that if for example my server calls a     write() to reply my client, and if my client does not have a corresponding     read() function, my server program will just hang there.

Currently I am thinking of using a simple timer to define a timeout count, and then to disconnect the client after a certain count, but I am wondering if there is a more elegant/or standard way of handling such errors?

Comment: What errors? The only error here is that the client isn't reading the messages being sent. That's an application protocol error, a program design error, not something you should be trying to bandaid over at runtime.

Answer (score 3):

There are two general approaches to prevent server blocking and to handle multiple clients by a single server instance:

- use POSIX threads to handle each client's connection. If one thread blocks because of erroneous client, other threads will still continue to run. If the remote client has just disappeared (crashed, network down, etc.), then sooner or later the TCP stack will signal a timeout and the blocked `write` operation will fail with error.
- use non-blocking I/O together with a polling mechanism, e.g. `select(2)` or `poll(2)`. It is quite harder to program using polling calls though. Network sockets are made non-blocking using `fcntl(2)` and in cases where a normal `write(2)` or `read(2)` on the socket would block an `EAGAIN` error is returned instead. You can use `select(2)` or `poll(2)` to wait for something to happen on the socket with an adjustable timeout period. For example, waiting for the socket to become writable, means that you will be notified when there is enough socket send buffer space, e.g. previously written data was flushed to the client machine TCP stack.

Answer (score 1):

If the client side isn't going to read from the socket anymore, it should close down the socket with `close`. And if you don't want to do that because the client still might want to write to the socket, then you should at least close the read half with `shutdown(fd, SHUT_RD)`.

This will set it up so the server gets an `EPIPE` on the write call.

If you don't control the clients... if random clients you didn't write can connect, the server should handle clients actively attempting to be malicious. One way for a client to be malicious is to attempt to force your server to hang. You should use a combination of non-blocking sockets and the timeout mechanism you describe to keep this from happening.

In general you should write the protocols for how the server and client communicate so that neither the server or client are trying to write to the socket when the other side isn't going to be reading. This doesn't mean you have to synchronize them tightly or anything. But, for example, HTTP is defined in such a way that it's quite clear for either side as to whether or not the other side is really expecting them to write anything at any given point in the protocol.